# How can I create a column based on the time difference of two tibble?

Tags: r

I have two tibbles:
[image]

my goal is to get the time difference, based on the column of `introduction_first` from the second tibble, so that the output looks like (time calculation starts at 2018-01-23):

[image]

---

Code for reproduction:

```
df_1 <- structure(list(itemID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), date14 = structure(c(17532, 17546, 17560, 
17574, 17588, 17602, 17616, 17630, 17644, 17658, 17672, 17686, 
17700, 17532, 17546, 17560, 17574, 17588, 17602, 17616), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

df_2 <- structure(list(itemID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20), introduction_first = structure(c(17554, 
17586, 17541, 17549, 17537, 17576, 17566, 17549, 17532, 17577, 
17532, 17534, 17565, 17547, 17535, 17548, 17546, 17538, 17532, 
17534), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can merge the datasets, and construct the `time_diff_h` column using `difftime()`:

```
library(dplyr)

inner_join(df_1,df_2, by="itemID") %>% 
  mutate(time_diff_h = as.numeric(difftime(date14,introduction_first, units="hours")),
         time_diff_h = if_else(time_diff_h<0, 0, time_diff_h)) %>% 
  select(-introduction_first)
```

Output:

```
   itemID date14     time_diff_h
    <dbl> <date>           <dbl>
 1      1 2018-01-01           0
 2      1 2018-01-15           0
 3      1 2018-01-29         144
 4      1 2018-02-12         480
 5      1 2018-02-26         816
 6      1 2018-03-12        1152
 7      1 2018-03-26        1488
 8      1 2018-04-09        1824
 9      1 2018-04-23        2160
10      1 2018-05-07        2496
11      1 2018-05-21        2832
12      1 2018-06-04        3168
13      1 2018-06-18        3504
14      2 2018-01-01           0
15      2 2018-01-15           0
16      2 2018-01-29           0
17      2 2018-02-12           0
18      2 2018-02-26          48
19      2 2018-03-12         384
20      2 2018-03-26         720
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R approach,

```
diffs <- transform(merge(df_1, df_2, by = 'itemID'), 
                   time_diff = as.numeric(difftime(date14, introduction_first, unit = 'hours')))$time_diff
df_1$time_diff <- replace(diffs, diffs < 0, 0)


   itemID     date14 time_diff
1       1 2018-01-01         0
2       1 2018-01-15         0
3       1 2018-01-29       144
4       1 2018-02-12       480
5       1 2018-02-26       816
6       1 2018-03-12      1152
7       1 2018-03-26      1488
8       1 2018-04-09      1824
9       1 2018-04-23      2160
10      1 2018-05-07      2496
11      1 2018-05-21      2832
12      1 2018-06-04      3168
13      1 2018-06-18      3504
14      2 2018-01-01         0
15      2 2018-01-15         0
16      2 2018-01-29         0
17      2 2018-02-12         0
18      2 2018-02-26        48
19      2 2018-03-12       384
20      2 2018-03-26       720
```